# Do my sentences have to be symmetrical when using the "not only...but also" grammar structure?

Tags: grammar

Normally, I write like this: "video games not only have a negative effect on children's social lives, but also on their health".

But a grammar website advised against writing like that, stating that if the "not only" part is not identical to the "but also" part, the sentence is ungrammatical.

To fix that sentence, according to the grammar website, I would have to say "video games not only have a negative effect on children's social lives, but they also have a damaging effect on their health". The thing is that this new symmetrical sentence sounds unnecessarily long and boring. So before I start writing like that, I want to know whether grammar rules actually require me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing **grammatically** wrong with what you wrote.

What you received is **stylistic** advice.

I myself would probably write

> Video games have a negative effect on children, not only on their social lives but also on their physical health.

But that is a preference about style, specifically about the rhetorical power of parallelism. It is not a rule of English grammar.

Comment: Or "...have a negative effect not only on children's social lives but also on their health."

Comment: @KateBunting You are of course right. Your version is perfectly grammatical and parallel. But style is personal. You have yours, which I admire, but I have mine as well. I was giving an example of my **personal** style. I like to place my “not only … but also” as close together as possible, and, to reinforce the parallelism, I prefer both nouns or neither noun to have an adjective.